# How to write a txt file on desktop using SQL script in Toad

Tags: sql, oracle, file, toad

I'm trying to write a simple txt file using SQL in Toad. Below is the SQL

```
create or replace directory dir_temp as 'C:\Users\name\Desktop\';
declare
  f utl_file.file_type;
begin
  f := utl_file.fopen('DIR_TEMP', 'something.txt', 'w');
  utl_file.fclose(f);
end;
/
```

This results into error:

```
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

I've verified the grants for Oracle user on directory. It has all permissions.
Also, I'm able to create spool file in the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

Directory should be created by SYS, and has to be located on the database server (OK, it *can* be elsewhere, but it usually isn't). If database isn't installed on your own computer but on some database server, then directory object points to a directory on the **server**, not your own PC.

If you do it properly, it works. I use 11gXE, installed on my laptop. Here's how:

Connected as `SYS`, I'm creating a directory and granting privileges to user (`SCOTT`) who will use it.

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL> create or replace directory dir_temp as 'c:\users\littlefoot\desktop';

Directory created.

SQL> grant read, write on directory dir_temp to scott;

Grant succeeded.
```

Connect as `Scott`; reuse code you wrote:

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
SQL> declare
  2    f utl_file.file_type;
  3  begin
  4    f := utl_file.fopen('DIR_TEMP', 'something.txt', 'w');
  5    utl_file.fclose(f);
  6  end;
  7  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Looks OK. Check whether the file was created:

```
SQL> $dir c:\users\littlefoot\desktop\*.txt
 Volume in drive C is OSDisk
 Volume Serial Number is 7635-F892

 Directory of c:\users\littlefoot\desktop

05.03.2020.  19:25                 0 something.txt
               1 File(s)              0 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  290.609.057.792 bytes free

SQL>
```

Right; the file is here (empty, though, but - it exists).

So, if you do it right, it *works*.

Comment: is there a way to create file on my PC or shared drive and not on the server. My ultimate goal is to export BLOB stored in DB to create PDF

Comment: Yes; you'd still have to create a directory, but this time using UNC.

Comment: can you provide details on how to use UNC

Comment: Sure. `create or replace directory dir_temp2 as '\\server_name\share_name\directory_name`. For example: `\\my-ias\d$\home\gis\images_4005`

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Please, edit your initial message and post all steps you performed, just like I did so that we could see what you did and how Oracle responded.